# Is it possible to run gitAction workflow on a newly created and randomly named branch?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I'd like to check code formatting when publishing new branch.

My situation is as follows.

- I checkout new branch (ex) branch-0XX ) based on develop branch
- I added some features and pushed those remotely (branch-0XX)
- I liked to check code formatting before requesting pull request to merge branch-0XX into develop branch.

I tried to use Github webhook to trigger a event when a new branch is created and I did it. However, the name of newly created branch is not static and I'm not sure whether it is possible to run jobs based on git action yaml file because I think the name of branch is added on yaml file.

I'm very new in Github and please let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the `push` [event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-workflow-only-when-a-push-to-specific-branches-occurs) in [combination with branch filters](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-and-excluding-branches) filter out your develop branch.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
      - '!develop'
```